# Facing problem in insert value into multiple row

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I am writing a PHP script where it takes data from a database table where there are more than ten rows. After taking all the rows' input from the database it adds with a variable. After that those sum value is inserted to all the rows of another database. My code is working fine in fetching all the rows' data from the database and add a number to that value. But it does not insert new data into another database. I am not getting any error messages. My code:

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM down_value";
$down_value_db = $conn->query($query);


/*Time Deference Variable*/
$td1=1;


$date = date("Y-m-d");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($down_value_db)) {
    /*Value from db*/

    $s_data1=$row['TGI_R'];

    /* Simulated Data*/

    $e_data1=$s_data1+$td1;

    //Insert Data into database
    $insert = $conn->query("INSERT into down_simulation (TGI_R,date) VALUES ('$e_data1', '$date')");

    if($insert){
        echo "$e_data1 <br/>Successfully data Recorded <br/>";
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    } 

}
```

?>

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: did you basic debugging, Also use instead of a php date the internal function NOW() to get the date

Answer (score -1):

you must add your select values to array and then with for loop insert this values to another table.

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"select tgi_r from down_value");
$tgi_r_array = array();
$date_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
        $tgi_r_array[] = $row['tgi_r']+1;
    }
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($tgi_r_array); $i++){
            $insert = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into down_simulation(tgi_r,date) values ('" . $tgi_r_array[$i] . "', '" . $date_time . "')");
        }

        print_r($tgi_r_array);
```

Comment: that is the same, only written differently, how would this help?